# How to use whitelists and prepared-statements with Postgresql in php?

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement, whitelist

I understand that I need to implement whitelists and prepared-statements into my php code. But I'm not sure how to do this with Postgresql and is it really necessary for my code? I'm using select lists to pass the users selected values to the query.

```
<?php

include "connect.php";

$table          = $_POST['tableSelected'];
$field          = $_POST['fieldSelected'];
$attribute      = $_POST['attributeSelected'];
$operator       = $_POST['operatorSelected'];
$fieldList      = $_POST['fieldList'];

$fieldstr = $fieldList . ",ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_Transform(l.geom,4326))";


$sql = "SELECT $fieldstr
        FROM $table l";

if (!empty($field) && !empty($operator) && !empty($attribute)) {
    $sql .= " WHERE {$field} {$operator} '{$attribute}'";
}

echo ($sql);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### White Listing

Your code in it's current form is very dangerous, not only do you allow the user to decide what fields should be selected but you also allow him to decide what tables to query on. You should definitely carry out white list checking on these. eg:

```
if($_POST['tableSelected'] == 'acceptable_table1' || $_POST['tableSelected'] == 'acceptable_table2) {
    $table = $_POST['tableSelected']
}
```

Similarly you should validate the field lists. But field list validation is going to be rather complicated because your fields are going to be dependent on the table. I suggest creating arrays and checking that the selection is in it.

```
$table1_fields = array('col1','col2',...)
$table2_fields = array('col1','col2',...)
```

### Prepared Statements

As you know prepared statements can only be used to bind parameters. They cannot be used to fill in table names and column names. That's why you need both prepared statements and white listing. I recommend using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). It might look something like

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT {$fieldlist} FROM {$table} where field = ?");
$stmt->execute(array('somevalue'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the problem is, my application is dynamic so is there a dynamic way to check the withe listing? I really don't wan't to hard code it?

Comment: Not easy. It would be like trying to reinvent something like phppgadmin.

Comment: Hmmm oké, that's not an option than :p Thanks for the information man!

Comment: Most welcome. Instead of using if else, you could use an array or a switch case to simplify matters but purely dynamic is hard

Comment: I have one more question. If I would only implement the white listing would that be sufficient to protect my application from sql injections?

Comment: no white listing is not sufficient. SQL injections can only be prevented by properly escaping user input and that is usually done internally when you use prepared statements.

Comment: can't I use `pg_escape_string()` to do that?